# jQuery selects only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select an `h3` wrap in a series of div and span. jQuery selects only one of the item and not all to modify them while I have sucessfully added a `div` after the same `div`

```
jQuery('div.meta > span > div').after('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
jQuery('div.meta > span > div > h3').css('font-size','11px');
jQuery('div.meta > span > div > h3').css('margin-right','8px');
```

The `.after()` function works well no sucess with the `.css()` one.

I have the following html repeated at the bottom of the page.

```
 <div class="meta"><span class="element element-counter first last">
     <div style="float: right;" id="realLifeEvidence">
      <h3 style="margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px; font-size: 11px;"><b>2164</b> total views</h3>
      </div>
   <div style="clear:both"> </div></span></div>
  <h1 class="title"> 
  <a href="/videos/real-life-evidence" title="Real-Life Evidence ">Real-Life Evidence </a> 
  </h1>
 <hr class="line">
</div>
```

The result can be seen here: http://www.ersvision.org/home/ the video's counter of "Nutritional Science in the Prevention & Management of COPD" has been modified not the other ones...

Comment: post your rough html structure please

Comment: "Weird Behavior" is not something anyone would search for if they had your problem.  What would you search for with this issue? That should be your title.  Also, we require that a minimal reproducible example be provided in your question; not in an external link. If the content behind that link changes, there's no way for us to see what it was before it changed.

Comment: The code work fine, just test it in the developper console on your browser.

Comment: So why _do_ you have a h3 in a span?

Comment: You're loading the content asynchronously so the headers don't exist yet when you try to style them. Why won't you put the styling you want in the `getYouTubeInfoV3` function?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/hkdojxu8/

Comment: Does this serve any purpose `$('div.meta > span > div').after('<div style="clear:both"></div>');`

Comment: @Popnoodles yes id does has the `div` containing the `h3` is floating and it breaks the layout.

Comment: @Juhana You are correct. The h3 that gets changed is the only h3 that exists from the start. So the solution is to simply put the CSS in the stylesheet instead of trying to be clever with jQuery.

Comment: @Mr Lister. That is the output... I am trying to style it.

Comment: @Juhana that is exactly it!!! it worked thank you. I did not think that it did not exist yet. Thank you. Write down an answer, and I ll select it.

Comment: @Wiglaf The problem is that you're trying to add `style` attributes to elements that don't exist yet. Put the styles in the stylesheet instead.

Comment: Closed questions can't be answered. Edit the question so that includes a complete example of the situation so it might get reopened.

Comment: Surely if `$('div.meta > span > div').after('<div style="clear:both"></div>')` does anything it just returns a jQuery object which isn't placed or used anywhere.

Comment: @Juhana you can now post an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution of my problem is found in the comment by @Juhana. Indeed I was trying to modify an element that was loaded asychronously and that was not yet present on the page.

Moving my code to the function `getYoutubeInfoV3`solved the issue.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Yes but there is no answer... Just comments, so I cannot vote up an answer. I just wanted to show what worked for me.

Comment: Encourage @Juhana to post the comment as an answer so that you can accept it, and perhaps edit your original post to show the solution

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier If you look at the comments I did. I did again.